# What happens if you give only one parameter to an Oracle PL/SL function that takes two parameters ?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is a function that takes two parameters :

```
FUNCTION RECUPERER_PARAMETRES_FTP

(pParamGenDomaine        VARCHAR2, pDestinataire           VARCHAR2)

...
```

What happens if I call this function only with one parameter :

```
RECUPERER_PARAMETRES_FTP('ECHANGE_202');
```

?

Does it consider this parameter as the first ? If yes, does it consider the second NULL ?

Comment: try it and see what happens?

Comment: A little more seriously though, I'm not all that familiar with Oracle, but I'd tend to guess that it will probably fail because of values not being defined.  I know this is the case in MS SQL unless you explicitly define default values.

Comment: You could also [look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#i17794), which includes: "A declaration and invocation match if their subprogram names and parameter lists match. The parameter lists match if each required formal parameter in the declaration has a corresponding actual parameter in the invocation." It gets slightly more interesting if you [supply default values](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#i6821), but your question doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

It's really, really not hard to set up a test case. You could create a function that has two parameters and then call it, or, if you don't want to store the function, you can declare a function in an anonymous block and then call it, like so:

```
declare
  function test1 (p1 number, p2 number)
  return number
  is
  begin
    return p1*p2;
  end;
begin
  test1(1);
end;
/

ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST1'
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 2):

... it will throw an error! You must explicitly declare a default value for the second parameter (default null) if you want to have the parameter set to null if omitted.

Comment: It won't through a compilation error; when calling a function you're not (necessarily) compiling it and even if you are you it can still compile.

Comment: How would it compile ?

Comment: The function compiles. The issue is not that it doesn't compile; the issue is that it's being called incorrectly. Incorrectly calling something does not throw compilation errors, even in the event that calling the function forces a recompile as it already compiles correctly.

Comment: You are right! Your explanation is more precise than mine, especially when not compiling code that invokes the function with a missing parameter.